# Cannot render ResultList using autoComplete.js

Tags: javascript, autocomplete

I'm testing autoComplete.js to get suggestions, but I cannot make ResultList to be shown. This is my simple input field:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tarekraafat/autocomplete.js@7.2.0/dist/js/autoComplete.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tarekraafat/autocomplete.js@7.2.0/dist/css/autoComplete.min.css">

<input type="text" id="autocomplete" name="fname">
```

And this is my JavaScript code:

```
const autoCompletejs = new autoComplete({
  data: {
    src: async () => suggest("party"),
    key: ["cname"],
    cache: false
  },
  trigger: {
    event: ["input"]
  },
  selector: "#autocomplete",
  resultsList: {
    render: true,
    container: source => {
      source.setAttribute("id", "company_name");
    },
    destination: document.querySelector("#autoComplete"),
    position: "afterend",
    element: "ul"
  }
});
```

Async function to get suggestions dynamically:

```
async function suggest(resource) {
  const query = document.querySelector("#autoComplete").value;
  var API_KEY = "6397a5215604df4cdda1109d8cdc08497d8284b2";
  const response = await fetch("https://suggestions.dadata.ru/suggestions/api/4_1/rs/suggest/" + resource, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': "Token " + API_KEY,
      'Content-Type': "application/json"
    },
    body: "{ \"query\": \"" + query + "\" }"
  });
  const data = await response.json();            
  return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you bug is at `return data` myabe this is returning your data but in your console not in your input but i'm not sure
also i think you have to do something like that

`autocomplete(document.getElementById("autocomplete"), data);`
or something like that 
hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Your `suggest` function returns the data inside of `suggestions` object which needs to be selected as shown below and in the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tarekraafat/2sthxw6b/1/.) link as well.

```
async function suggest(resource) {
  const query = document.querySelector("#autoComplete").value;
  var API_KEY = "6397a5215604df4cdda1109d8cdc08497d8284b2";
  const response = await fetch("https://suggestions.dadata.ru/suggestions/api/4_1/rs/suggest/" + resource, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': "Token " + API_KEY,
      'Content-Type': "application/json"
    },
    body: "{ \"query\": \"" + query + "\" }"
  });
  const data = await response.json();            
  return data.suggestions;
}
```